# Webdriver shows blank screen in Xcode for iphone simulator testing

Tags: iphone, xcode

Firstly, When I launch Webdriver application in Xcode. I see blank screen. I do not seen any url as mentioned in the webdriver help document.

Secondly, I tried configuring selenium webdirver(I followed the steps as mentioned in this [link](http://ios-driver.github.io/ios-driver/setup.html))

When I try to launch ios server, I get error as shown below.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
 /Users/Test/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Webdriver-
fmrsobbkmfscegexfkhhgcgijkvx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Webdriver.app isn't
 an IOS app.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got the solution for this problem. I downloaded selenium source code using SVN instead of GIT and It started working fine.